# Passing sequence of commands to a running container

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes

I have a executed  `command1 | command2`  which runs from inside a container.

I am trying to run the same command by passing it to the running container, but it doesn't work.
I tried `kubectl -n namespace exec -it pod -- 'command1 | command2'`

Any ideas? If pipes are not supported, any alternatives to run these 2 commands in sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to the `kubectl exec` command are executed directly, without a shell. Because you're passing not a single command but a shell expression, this isn't going to work.

The solution is to explicitly invoke the shell:

```
kubectl -n namespace exec -it pod -- sh -c 'command1 | command2'
```

For example:

```
$ kubectl exec -it fedora0 -- sh -c 'echo hello world | sed s/hello/goodbye/'
goodbye world
```